# Diferença entre Multi e Single Thread

Tags: node.js, apache, servidor

Em termos de processos, qual a diferença do multi-thread pro single-thread?
Como as duas formas vão trabalhar com uma requisição?

Comment: Salvo eu estar enganado o NodeJS só funciona com uma *thread*. O Apache sim funciona nos dois modos. Dê uma informação melhor sobre o que você quer saber.

Comment: A diferença entre eles em termos de processo.
Uma vez que eu tenha feito a requisição, como o servidor lida com ela no multi e no single.

Answer (score 3):

Tem mais arquiteturas além de single-thread (ST) e multi-thread (MT). Basicamente o ST só pode tratar uma requisição de cada vez, então o processamento de cada uma não pode ser demorado, nem pode bloquear (por exemplo, ficar esperando pelo banco de dados). O MT, assumindo que se crie uma thread por requisição, pode tratar várias requisições em paralelo, mesmo que demorem ou bloqueiem.

Um servidor ST pode ser eficaz, desde que nunca bloqueie. O Node.js é assíncrono de modo a não bloquear. Qualquer processamento demorado deve ser delegado a um outro processo, o que também pode ser feito no Node com subprocess.

Outra forma de abordar o problema: o prefork do Apache cria um pool de subprocessos, e delega as requisições para cada subprocesso conforme elas chegam. Isto garante o paralelismo e evita as complexidades de programação MT. Isto pode ser implementado também no Node mas o Apache entrega isto de fábrica, o que facilita a vida do desenvolvedor PHP por exemplo, pois ele não precisa se preocupar se está bloqueando.